# What are all the endings of Façade and how do I find them?

Tags: facade

The game [*Façade*](http://www.interactivestory.net/) weaves an interesting tale of deception and romance over the course of its short gameplay, one that varies in many subtle and not-so-subtle ways from playthrough to playthrough, but ultimately ends in one of a few basic outcomes based on your behavior. For example:

> One ending has you getting kicked out of the house by your angry friends, for annoying or shocking them too many times.

What are all the basic endings to *Façade*? What sort of behavior leads to getting each ending?

Comment: You could pruchase the [Behind the Façade guide](http://www.interactivestory.net/goodies/behindthefacade.html)...

Comment: My teacher told us to write a three page story...I wrote mine on making Grace leave. YEAH BUDDY! :D

Answer (score 5):

Endings I've found so far:

1. Get kicked out: say enough offensive things or make enough unwanted advances. (Talking about Grace's melons is an easy way to trigger this outcome.)
2. Get Grace to leave: ask Grace a lot of "why" questions and whether she's happy/loves Trip, etc. When Grace asks whether everything you've been asking has been toward some particular purpose, say no, and she'll choose this course of action; saying yes will cause her to admit to sleeping with a fellow artist, but she'll still leave.
3. Get Trip to admit to the affair with Maria and then leave: direct your questions primarily toward Trip along the same lines as number 2 above; when he asks if everything is adding up to something, say yes.
4. Get Trip to admit to the affair AND get Grace to admit to sleeping with Vince, and they wind up staying together: just like in question 3, except answer "no" to Trip's question.
5. Have Trip admit to being ashamed of his parents in comparison to Grace's parents. This will make him break up with Grace and leave. This consists of siding with Trip mainly until him and Grace start asking you yes or no questions.

Comment: I got Grace to admit to her passion for art but still stay with Trip in one playthrough; not really sure what the details were since this was a few months back.

Comment: Yeah, the asymmetry of the situation makes me think there's an ending or two that I'm not finding, but I don't know what factors I need to be paying attention to in order to get further. However, I'm going to be out-of-town for the weekend, so I didn't want the question to remain unanswered after the bounty expired, in case I forgot about it.

Comment: I am wondering if Melon is a glitch or an easter egg.

Answer (score 3):

I got Trip to admit that he purposefully asked her to marry him in front of a public to force her into it, and also that he just can't accept the idea of having an artist wife, hence pushing her into advertising instead. They calmed down and said they'd need to talk it over, and wished me a good night.

As for what I did to get this ending, I picked up the 8-ball and quoted it through almost all of the scene («Ball says "Maybe"»), said random but unoffensive crap, pointed at everything, and told Trip, who asked me if I was leading up to something: "Nah it was just random crap." :P

Still, it was a very satisfying ending for the very low amount of meaningful input I've given this thing :P

Answer (score 3):

I flirted and kissed Grace (agreeing about everything and saying she looked good somehow made me able to do that) and told (lots of times) that Trip cheated on her with Maria. In the end, both were uncomfortable, and akward Grace and mad Trip insisted that everything was fine with their marriage and that i should leave. After they close the door on you, you can hear them saying:

> *Trip:* You were something else tonight!
>   *Grace:* How could you say such
>   things about me?
>   *Trip:* Me?! What the fuck were you thinking?
>   *Grace:*
>   You have so many problems i don't even know what to do!

Also, note that in every game, there is a time near the end where they say about what you've told them. I noticed that the combination of those things defines the ending.

```
What you've been saying, about marriage/trip/grace/communication/love/blah. Do you think that saiying that trip is cheating on me/we don't communicate/trip's stuff/grace's parents/blah blah is really going to add something?
```

And then there is an ending for "Yes" and one for "No". The number of ending is the squared number of subjects times 2 (maybe less, since sometimes diffrent things lead to a same ending, while some don't even matter).

Answer (score 1):

I got them say "Thank you, you really helped us tonight. We're okay, really. You should go home now." and then it let me walk myself out with the arrows. All I did was talk about Maria when I first got the house, said random crap until they're in the conversation where they're asking you Yes or No. Then when Trip/Grace asks you if you want the truth, say No, and when they ask you say if it's supposed to mean something say Yes.

Answer (score -2):

I got Trip to actually walk out of the apartment. He was furious, ended the marriage, and walked out. I hardly did anything!

Comment: What actions did you do or not to reach this ending?